# How can I open a folder in the current finder window?

Tags: finder, applescript

I know `tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/folder/path/"` will open a *new* finder window, how can I open a folder in the **current** finder window?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the target of the front Finder window to (POSIX file "/folder/path/")
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to open a new Finder window when there are no open Finder windows (or only for example a preferences window is open), use the `reopen` command:

```
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    set target of Finder window 1 to (POSIX file "/tmp/")
end tell
```